# Java String split operation

Tags: java, string

When I split a string in java as shown in code below, it gives length as 3.

```
String data = "DK4..||VSDK4|";

String[] tokens = data.split("\\|");

System.out.println(tokens.length);
```

However it should be 4, what could be the reason behind this?

Comment: why should it be 4?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) "Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array."

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca If you post that as an answer, I shall upvote it.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem done :)

Comment: Why did you downvote the question? Isn't it a valid question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess it's because it would have been easily answered by reading the documentation, so it showed a lack of effort on your part to find the solution on your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [`split` method documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-):

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

This is because `split` with a single argument calls `split` with second argument as `0`, which, according to that method's [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)

> If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

Answer (score 3):

See the doc of [`split(String regex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>   This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero. **Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array**.

You can use [`split(String regex, int limit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) with a negative `limit` to get all:

`String[] tokens = data.split("\\|", -1);`

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as
>   possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the
>   pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have
>   any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.